# Crossgen compilation in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have been using .NET Core for some time now. And I have created a Console App. Everything works however I heard that I can compile .NET Core app assembly into a native assembly using CrossGen. Which quoting their documentation:

> To help make your app start up faster, CoreCLR includes a tool called CrossGen, which can pre-compile the MSIL code into native code.

I have been trying for a long time right now and I have really no idea, how can I do this. There is really little documentation for CrossGen and even less questions here at StackOverflow.

How can I compile my .NET Core App to native code using CrossGen on a Mac?
I'd appreciate if somebody could answer this question with given examples.

Comment: They are banging the drum on .NETCore 1.0 right now.  But it doesn't include [CoreRT](https://github.com/dotnet/corert), a CLR version that's optimized for native AOT.  It is rumored to work on Macs, the multitude of Linux distros appear to be the hangup.  There is a lot of push-back from users that want their desktop app to work, not making this any easier.  Just wait until it is done.

Answer (score 5):

crossgen is a tool that comes bundled with CoreCLR in the NuGet package, or is built alongside it from source. The OSX runtime package for CoreCLR [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/runtime.osx.10.10-x64.Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime.CoreCLR/) has crossgen in `tools/crossgen` path inside the nuget archive.

If you run the tool without any arguments, it should give you basic usage instructions. Generally, what you will want to do is run `crossgen <path-to-your-app>`.